# Sum of odd elements in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have to sum odd elementс that are on odd positions. This is not working. Can someone tell me where is my mistake? Thank you

```
(defun sum (list)
  (cond
    ((null list) 0)
    ((= (mod 2 (car list)) 0) (sum (cddr list)))
    (T (+ (car list) (sum (cddr list))))))
```

Comment: What does that mean 'it is not working'?

Comment: why using mod if [oddp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_evenpc.htm) would work just as fine and is a bite more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the order of the arguments of the function mod. It should be:

```
(= (mod (car list) 2) 0)
```

To avoid this mistake, you can use the function evenp instead.

Answer (score 6):

Your original definition (sum odd elements at odd positions) actually translates into a **loop** very cleanly:

```
(loop for i from 0 
  for x in '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
  when (and (oddp i) (oddp x))
  sum x)
```

Your original solution moved down the list by **cddr**, which is actually a pretty nice way to do this.  You can do it with **loop** as well (the initial call to **rest** is just to get things started at index 1):

```
(loop for x in (rest '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6)) by #'cddr
   when (oddp x)
   sum x)
```

Comment: @Baggers Yup :) It's: `for-as-in-list::= var [type-spec] in form1 [by step-fun] `